# including a notmapped property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

We have a class which has notmapped property:

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual IEnumerable<SM_SITE> SITES { get; set; }
```

This was done as some queries (linq) do not need to include the SITES.  but this is causing an issue when we need it, is there anyway to include it back on certain queries?

Comment: You can remove NotMapped, and the functions that you dont need SM_Sites, you can use:  db.Entity<EntityName>().Exclude(e => e.Attribute) OR db.Entity<EntityName>().Ignore(e => e.Attribute)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **NotMapped** attribute can be applied to properties of an entity class for which we do not want to create corresponding columns in the database. So it is not possible to reach a column which is not created.

If you want to reach that column when it is necessary, **you should remove *NotMapped* attribute first.**

**1)** You can use **Explicit Loading**. First remove **virtual** keyword and reach SITES as shown below;

```
var yourData = context.YourEntity...//how filter you want for the following
context.Entry(yourData).Reference(s => s.STIES).Load();
```

**Now *yourData* includes *SITES* too.**

But it queries DB 2 times (performance issue may be problem)

**2)** You can use **Eager Loading**.First remove **virtual** keyword. In eager loading, unless you don't use **Include** method, your owned entity (SITES) won't be included. You can include owned entities with eager load when it's necessary with **Include** keyword as

```
context.YourEntity.Include(x=>x.SITES)...//how filter you want for the following
```

**3)** You can use **Lazy Loading**.You can reach SITES as shown below;

```
var yourData = context.YourEntity...//how filter you want for the following
var sitesData = yourData.SITES;
```

But it queries DB 2 times (performance issue may be problem)
**(Known as n+1 issue)**

**If you say my *NotMapped* attribute is a must then;**

**4)** Don't remove **NotMapped** attribute. Add **SITES** table to database manuelly. Create a SP (Stored Procedure) which gets the entity with **SITES**. You can call this SP when you want to include **SITES** in your entity.