# Return NotMapped property value from .NET

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have this property `NamePrefix` that has a `[NotMapped]` property because it's a computed column and was making problems when I was doing `InsertAsync()`. However, I need this value in some cases and now as I have this `[NotMapped]`, I get `NULL` for it. Is there a way to get this value? This is how I have it mapped:

```
[NotMapped]
[StringLength(256)]
public string NamePrefix { get; set; }
```

This is where I retrieve this value through a SQL query:

```
var query = (SQLQuery p) 
select new RequestObject {
NamePrefix = p.NamePrefix,
}).ToListAsync();
```

I followed this [example (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880770/including-a-notmapped-property) and added `.Include()`, but was still getting nulls.

```
var query = (SQLQuery p) 
select new RequestObject {
NamePrefix = p.NamePrefix,
}).Include(x => x.NamePrefix).ToListAsync();
```

Is there a way to get this `[NotMapped]` value from the way I do it?

Comment: When you add NotMapped metadata, the property is not persisted in the database and there is no way you can retrieve it. You say that it is a computed property but there is a setter. I doubt that it is a computed property. Additionally .Include is used for relations (join tables).

Comment: Your question fall into the XY category. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem You should not use `[NotMapped]` in the first place but `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`.

Comment: have you tried like `public string NamePrefix =>10/2` as you say it is calculated value. this way it will be calculated automatically based on your calculation params

Comment: Thank you all. @Orace's answer did fix my problem